# NumPy: Execute function over each ndarray element

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have a three dimensional ndarray of 2D coordinates, for example:

```
[[[1704 1240]
  [1745 1244]
  [1972 1290]
  [2129 1395]
  [1989 1332]]

 [[1712 1246]
  [1750 1246]
  [1964 1286]
  [2138 1399]
  [1989 1333]]

 [[1721 1249]
  [1756 1249]
  [1955 1283]
  [2145 1399]
  [1990 1333]]]
```

The ultimate goal is to remove the point closest to a given point ([1989 1332]) from each "group" of 5 coordinates.  My thought was to produce a similarly shaped array of distances, and then using argmin to determine the indices of the values to be removed.  However, I am not certain how to go about applying a function, like one to calculate a distance to a given point, to every element in an ndarray, at least in a NumPythonic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List comprehensions are a very inefficient way to deal with numpy arrays.  They're an especially poor choice for the distance calculation.

To find the difference between your data and a point, you'd just do `data - point`. You can then calculate the distance using `np.hypot`, or if you'd prefer, square it, sum it, and take the square root.

It's a bit easier if you make it an Nx2 array for the purposes of the calculation though.

Basically, you want something like this:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[[1704, 1240],
                  [1745, 1244],
                  [1972, 1290],
                  [2129, 1395],
                  [1989, 1332]],

                 [[1712, 1246],
                  [1750, 1246],
                  [1964, 1286],
                  [2138, 1399],
                  [1989, 1333]],

                 [[1721, 1249],
                  [1756, 1249],
                  [1955, 1283],
                  [2145, 1399],
                  [1990, 1333]]])

point = [1989, 1332]

#-- Calculate distance ------------
# The reshape is to make it a single, Nx2 array to make calling `hypot` easier
dist = data.reshape((-1,2)) - point
dist = np.hypot(*dist.T)

# We can then reshape it back to AxBx1 array, similar to the original shape
dist = dist.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1], 1)
print dist
```

This yields:

```
array([[[ 299.48121811],
        [ 259.38388539],
        [  45.31004304],
        [ 153.5219854 ],
        [   0.        ]],

       [[ 290.04310025],
        [ 254.0019685 ],
        [  52.35456045],
        [ 163.37074401],
        [   1.        ]],

       [[ 280.55837182],
        [ 247.34186868],
        [  59.6405902 ],
        [ 169.77926846],
        [   1.41421356]]])
```

Now, removing the closest element is a bit harder than simply getting the closest element.

With numpy, you can use boolean indexing to do this fairly easily.

However, you'll need to worry a bit about the alignment of your axes.

The key is to understand that numpy "broadcasts" operations along the *last* axis.  In this case, we want to brodcast along the middle axis.

Also, `-1` can be used as a placeholder for the size of an axis. Numpy will calculate the permissible size when `-1` is put in as the size of an axis.

What we'd need to do would look a bit like this:

```
#-- Remove closest point ---------------------
mask = np.squeeze(dist) != dist.min(axis=1)
filtered = data[mask]

# Once again, let's reshape things back to the original shape...
filtered = filtered.reshape(data.shape[0], -1, data.shape[2])
```

You could make that a single line, I'm just breaking it down for readability.  The key is that `dist != something` yields a boolean array which you can then use to index the original array.

So, Putting it all together:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[[1704, 1240],
                  [1745, 1244],
                  [1972, 1290],
                  [2129, 1395],
                  [1989, 1332]],

                 [[1712, 1246],
                  [1750, 1246],
                  [1964, 1286],
                  [2138, 1399],
                  [1989, 1333]],

                 [[1721, 1249],
                  [1756, 1249],
                  [1955, 1283],
                  [2145, 1399],
                  [1990, 1333]]])

point = [1989, 1332]

#-- Calculate distance ------------
# The reshape is to make it a single, Nx2 array to make calling `hypot` easier
dist = data.reshape((-1,2)) - point
dist = np.hypot(*dist.T)

# We can then reshape it back to AxBx1 array, similar to the original shape
dist = dist.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1], 1)

#-- Remove closest point ---------------------
mask = np.squeeze(dist) != dist.min(axis=1)
filtered = data[mask]

# Once again, let's reshape things back to the original shape...
filtered = filtered.reshape(data.shape[0], -1, data.shape[2])

print filtered
```

Yields:

```
array([[[1704, 1240],
        [1745, 1244],
        [1972, 1290],
        [2129, 1395]],

       [[1712, 1246],
        [1750, 1246],
        [1964, 1286],
        [2138, 1399]],

       [[1721, 1249],
        [1756, 1249],
        [1955, 1283],
        [2145, 1399]]])
```

On a side note, if more than one point is equally close, this won't work. Numpy arrays have to have the same number of elements along each dimension, so you'll need to re-do your grouping in that case.

Comment: Ah, somehow I didn't see this before I posted. I thought of using `apply_along_axis`, but I tested it and this is much faster.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` should use less memory, though, so both approaches are still useful!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're looking for [`apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html). Using `numpy`'s built-in broadcasting, we can simply subtract the point from the array:

```
>>> a - numpy.array([1989, 1332])
array([[[-285,  -92],
        [-244,  -88],
        [ -17,  -42],
        [ 140,   63],
        [   0,    0]],

       [[-277,  -86],
        [-239,  -86],
        [ -25,  -46],
        [ 149,   67],
        [   0,    1]],

       [[-268,  -83],
        [-233,  -83],
        [ -34,  -49],
        [ 156,   67],
        [   1,    1]]])
```

Then we can apply `numpy.linalg.norm` to it:

```
>>> dist = a - numpy.array([1989, 1332])
>>> numpy.apply_along_axis(numpy.linalg.norm, 2, dist)
array([[ 299.48121811,  259.38388539,   45.31004304,  
         153.5219854 ,    0.        ],
       [ 290.04310025,  254.0019685 ,   52.35456045,  
         163.37074401,    1.        ],
       [ 280.55837182,  247.34186868,   59.6405902 ,  
         169.77926846,    1.41421356]])
```

Finally, some boolean mask trickery, along with a couple of `reshape` calls:

```
>>> a[normed != normed.min(axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))].reshape((3, 4, 2))
array([[[1704, 1240],
        [1745, 1244],
        [1972, 1290],
        [2129, 1395]],

       [[1712, 1246],
        [1750, 1246],
        [1964, 1286],
        [2138, 1399]],

       [[1721, 1249],
        [1756, 1249],
        [1955, 1283],
        [2145, 1399]]])
```

Joe Kington's answer is faster though. Oh well. I'll leave this for posterity.

```
def joes(data, point):
    dist = data.reshape((-1,2)) - point
    dist = np.hypot(*dist.T)
    dist = dist.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1], 1)
    mask = np.squeeze(dist) != dist.min(axis=1)
    return data[mask].reshape((3, 4, 2))

def mine(a, point):
    dist = a - point
    normed = numpy.apply_along_axis(numpy.linalg.norm, 2, dist)
    return a[normed != normed.min(axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))].reshape((3, 4, 2))

>>> %timeit mine(data, point)
1000 loops, best of 3: 586 us per loop
>>> %timeit joes(data, point)
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.9 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but here is one using list comprehensions:

Distance function:

```
In [35]: from numpy.linalg import norm

In [36]: dist = lambda x,y:norm(x-y)
```

Input data:

```
In [39]: GivenMatrix = scipy.rand(3, 5, 2)

In [40]: GivenMatrix
Out[40]: 
array([[[ 0.83798666,  0.90294439],
        [ 0.8706959 ,  0.88397176],
        [ 0.91879085,  0.93512921],
        [ 0.15989245,  0.57311869],
        [ 0.82896003,  0.53589968]],

       [[ 0.0207089 ,  0.9521768 ],
        [ 0.94523963,  0.31079109],
        [ 0.41929482,  0.88559614],
        [ 0.87885236,  0.45227422],
        [ 0.58365369,  0.62095507]],

       [[ 0.14757177,  0.86101539],
        [ 0.58081214,  0.12632764],
        [ 0.89958321,  0.73660852],
        [ 0.3408943 ,  0.45420989],
        [ 0.42656333,  0.42770216]]])

In [41]: q = scipy.rand(2)

In [42]: q
Out[42]: array([ 0.03280889,  0.71057403])
```

Compute output distances:

```
In [44]: distances = [[dist(x, q) for x in SubMatrix] 
                      for SubMatrix in GivenMatrix]

In [45]: distances
Out[45]: 
[[0.82783910695733931,
  0.85564093542511577,
  0.91399620574915652,
  0.18720096539588818,
  0.81508758596405939],
 [0.24190557184498068,
  0.99617079746515047,
  0.42426891258164884,
  0.88459501973012633,
  0.55808740166908177],
 [0.18921712490174292,
  0.80103146210692744,
  0.86716521557255788,
  0.40079819635686459,
  0.48482888965287363]]
```

To rank the results for each submatrix:

```
In [46]: scipy.argsort(distances)
Out[46]: 
array([[3, 4, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4, 3, 1],
       [0, 3, 4, 1, 2]])
```

As for the deletion, I personally think that's easiest by converting `GivenMatrix` to a `list`, then using `del`:

```
>>> GivenList = GivenMatrix.tolist()

>>> del GivenList[1][2] # delete third row from the second 5-by-2 submatrix
```